# How come my attribute–directive isn't triggered?

Tags: angularjs

I have created element-dierectives before. I just tried to create a simple element-dierective. Here it is in it's simplest form:

```
.directive('gdShow', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            console.log('elem');
        },
    };
});
```

This is how I try to call it:

```
<div gdShow="test" class="wrapper">
    "stuff"
</div>
```

This works for my element directives, but not for this one, why?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it but as I had already written the question I though I might post it for any future internet-travelers.

The attribute is supppose to be gd-show, like this:

```
<div gd-show="test" class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: +1 for not leaving question unanswered. Also note that it's standard to use lowercase letters (`gd-show`).